# Adding another section onto the website breaks my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am developing a website for a school project and I am currently stumped. I have created a video carousel and it runs via the use of JavaScript. However, when I try to re-create the same carousel for other videos, it completely breaks the previous one. It doesn't make sense I am not re-using any variables or anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var pos = 0,
  slides = $('.slide'),
  numOfSlides = slides.length;

function nextSlide() {
  stopCurrentVideo();
  slides.eq(pos).animate({
    left: '-100%'
  }, 500);
  pos = pos >= numOfSlides - 1 ? 0 : ++pos;
  slides.eq(pos).css({
    left: '100%'
  }).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 500);
}

function previousSlide() {
  stopCurrentVideo();
  slides.eq(pos).animate({
    left: '100%'
  }, 500);
  pos = pos == 0 ? numOfSlides - 1 : --pos;
  slides.eq(pos).css({
    left: '-100%'
  }).animate({
    left: 0
  }, 500);
}

function stopCurrentVideo() {
  $('.slider-video:eq(' + pos + ')').load().removeAttr('controls')
    .siblings('.overlay-content').show().find('.play-button').show();
}

$('.left').click(previousSlide);
$('.right').click(nextSlide);
```

```css
.video-slider {
  width: 850px;
  height: 20em;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide:first-child {
  left: 0;
}

.video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.slide-arrow {
  background: url(images/arrowright.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.slide-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-arrow:after {
  content: "\003c";
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.slide-arrow.right:after {
  content: "\003e";
}

.slide-arrow.right {
  background: url(images/arrowleft.png) no-repeat;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>Most Recent YouTube Videos:<br><br></h3>
  <div class="video-slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hWJAE_Xj3Wo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OI6YWqYNISE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AVYrI5I9iF4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G6cvyaOPeRE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3R38DKLFqa8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-arrow left"></div>
    <div class="slide-arrow right"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./yt.js"></script>
  </div>
</section>
```

Completely separate carousel I am trying to make:

```
<section>
<h3>Most Recent Instagram Videos:<br><br></h3>
        <div class="insta">
            <div class="slider2">
            <video src="content/1.mp4" width="560" height="315"></video>
            </div>
            <div class="slider2">
            <video src="content/2.mp4" width="560" height="315"></video>
            </div>
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./ig.js"></script>   
</div>
    
</section>
```

I am new to this so lack any deep knowledge, explicit explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: If you look multiple sections and they all have the same scructure, then you first of all loads scripts multiple times. Avoid this. second you need to redesign your script so it can handle multiple sections

Comment: So how would you suggest I go about fixing this? call the scripts earlier like in the <head> section?